# python: is dictionary lookup O(1) when iterating keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say i have a dictionary

```
mydict = {}
mydict["apple"] = 1
mydict["oranges"] =1
```

Is there BigO difference in the below?

```
if "apple" in mydict
```

vs

```
if "apple" in mydict.iterkeys()
```

is the latter lookup still O(1) or O(num_of_keys)?

Comment: With the _old, outdated, antiquated_ python, it is O(n) (yet another reason to upgrade, eh?).

Comment: `iterkeys()`: iter is for "iterating". So yes `O(n)`. Note that `.keys()` behave the same complexity-wise with old 2.x

Comment: so I should use "if "apple" in mydict" instead of iterkeys()

Comment: @ealeon yes, if you are doing a membership test on a `dict`,  **always** use `if some_thing in mydict:`. This is *especially* true in Python 2.

Comment: If for some reason, you really wanted to be explicit about the keys, you could do `if "apple" in mydict.viewkeys()`, but knowing about `viewkeys` is probably less common than knowing about what `in` does with dicts. Also, it's not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: the duplicate is about `keys()` but you can take it for granted that it's the same answer for `iterkeys()`, now removed from python 3